# Accessing earlier Windows restore points by restoring to the earliest date

Tags: windows-7, system-restore

In a last ditch effort to recover some files, I was wondering if it was possible to restore to the earliest restore point on my computer (say June 2014), and then have the restore points that were available at that date available (say March 2014). In other words, can I continually restore to an earlier time, each time restoring to the earliest point available? Or maybe a better phrasing would be, are restore points a static set of memory, or is each set of restore points available associated with each restore point?

Answer (score 3):

According to this [article](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-ca/windows7/how-much-disk-space-does-system-restore-require), Windows removes restore points when it's assigned memory is full.

> System Restore might use between three and five percent of the space
>   on each disk. As the amount of space fills up with restore points, it
>   deletes older restore points to make room for new ones. System Restore
>   doesn't run on disks smaller than 1 gigabyte (GB).
>
> You can manage the disk space that is used by System Restore by
>   following these steps:
>
> 1. Open System by clicking the Start button [image], right-clicking Computer, and then clicking Properties.
> 2. In the left pane, click **System protection**. Administrator permission will be required.  If you're prompted for an administrator
>      password or confirmation, type the password or provide confirmation.
> 3. Under **Protection Settings**, click the disk, and then click Configure.
> 4. Under **Disk Space Usage**, move the slider to the right to increase the disk space that system protection can use or move the
>      slider to the left to decrease the disk space.
>
> [image]

If you did not adjust these settings to allow additional space then the previous restore points are likely gone.

Comment: Those are your reputation points @ramhound. :)

Comment: Its alright.  I figured you were in a rush.  Your past answers are indication of quality.  I couldn't stand a link only answer though :-)

Comment: I'm generally fairly terse. :|

Comment: So does this mean that each restore point uses the same allocated memory? Or can each restore point have it's own X GB of memory allocated for them?

Comment: You cannot restore what is gone. You can follow the instructions to allow more points in the future.

Comment: I understand that. I'm asking if restore points are "global", or if each restore point has it's own set of restore points previous to it. I'm guessing not, but wanted to double check, thus this question. If I restore to a previous point, are all the restore points that were available at that time still available?